# How to Make Constants in an Expect Script?

Tags: bash, constants, expect

I would like to be able to create and set the value of constants in an Expect script.

In scripts such as Bash and a great many programming languages, one can create and assign a value to a constant. I have tried many online sites looking how to do this in Expect, but I have surprisingly not been able to come across this basic information.

Creating and assigning a variable named `name` in Bash: `name="Bob"`

Creating and assigning a constant named `CONFIG_FILE` in Bash: `readonly CONFIG_FILE="Configuration.ini"`

Creating and assigning a variable named `copyPath` in Expect: `set copyPath "/home/bob/tmp"`

Creating and assigning a constant in Expect: ?????

How does one create and set the value of constants in an Expect script?

Comment: Expect uses TCL, an independent and general purpose scripting language which was basically the Python of its day (but now rarely seen outside of Expect). Look up a TCL language reference guide

Comment: Here's a Tcl wiki entry: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/constants

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Comment: Thanks @pynexj, I will!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Python, TCL (the scripting language used for Expect) doesn't have constants.

I would suggest going the python route. Define them in all caps, don't change them and hope everyone else gets the hint.

```
set COPYPATH "/home/bob/tmp"
set PI 3.14159265359
```

If you really think you need them, there are some hacks in the link glenn jackman posted in the comments https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/constants.

Comment: This was what I was afraid of. Thank you for your reply!